# ApplyUpdates no REST com Firedac

Tags: json, delphi, rest, datasnap, firedac

Estou fazendo um projeto que usa um servidor REST com *FireDac*.

Utilizo uma função Genérica para dar meus `select` mas quando tento dar meu `ApplyUpdates` ele não da erro nenhum mas os dados não são refletidos no DB.

Meu `Applyupdates`:

```
function TServerMethods.ApplyUpdates(banco, tabela : String; const DeltaList: TFDJSONDeltas; var Mensagem : String) : Boolean; 
var 
  LApply : IFDJSONDeltasApplyUpdates; 
  Query : TFDQuery; 
begin 
  mensagem := ''; 
  result := false; 
  try 
    try 
      LApply := TFDJSONDeltasApplyUpdates.Create(DeltaList); 
      Query := CriaQuery(banco,Tabela); 
      Query.Open(); 
      LApply.ApplyUpdates(banco + '.' + tabela, Query.Command); 
      if LApply.Errors.Count > 0 then 
        raise Exception.Create(LApply.Errors.Strings.ToString); 
      result := true; 
    except 
      on E:Exception do 
      begin 
        mensagem := 'Ocorreu um Erro na atualização: ' + #13#10 + E.Message; 
      end; 
    end; 
  finally 

  end; 

end;
```

Acredito que o problema esteja aqui mas existe a vaga possibilidade do erro estar no meu *binding* (que gero em tempo de execução).

Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Quando invocamos o método ApplyUpdates em uma FDQuery devemos lembrar que exceções não serão geradas para a aplicação, porem o FireDac registra o erro em uma estrutura de registro de dados interna e continua a processar atualizações até que o número de erros seja igual ou superior a AMaxErrors.

Após chamar o método ApplyUpdates , devemos incluir rtHasErrors em FilterChanges para filtrarmos os registros que contenham erros. Em seguida, navegamos através do conjunto de dados e lemos a propriedade RowError que conterá um objeto de exceção associado ao registro atual. Como mostra o exemplo abaixo:

```
var
  oErr: EFDException;
begin
if FDQuery1.ApplyUpdate > 0 then begin
  FDQuery1.FilterChanges := [rtModified, rtInserted, rtDeleted, rtHasErrors];
  try
    FDQuery1.First;
    while not FDQuery1.Eof do begin
      oErr := FDQuery1.RowError;
      if oErr <> nil then begin
        raise Exception.Create(oErr.Message);
      end;
      FDQuery1.Next;
    end;
  finally
    FDQuery1.FilterChanges := [rtUnmodified, rtModified, rtInserted];
  end;
end;
```